# GWT : Class 'java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture' is not present in JRE Emulation INTELLIJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt

I am working on a GWT project in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2023.3.2

All is running fine.

But IntelliJ keeps telling me that java class files are not present in JRE Emulation Library.

Please help :)

[image]

Class 'java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture' is not present in JRE Emulation Library so it cannot be used in client code of 'com.srr.ShopManager' GWT module

Sorry did forget to add source is included from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ekotrope</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-completablefuture</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: we are using it it's only a false warning : All is running fine.

Comment: Not your down-voter, but it is only one DV. Why the comment?

Comment: Is it possible to provide sample project example?

Comment: ah did hear IntelliJ is not parsing pom dependency

Comment: Do you mean that dependencies are not added properly?

Answer (score 0):

Only solution is to disable inspection Warning in IntelliJ